# jQuery-Rails or jRails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) ruby gem & [jRails](http://mirror.ozdiy.com/assets/b8/2f96a12bc919b37e09d303b86ea1b9_1251811910.html). I *think* they both cover ways of adding jQuery, but are installed in different ways? If so, which is the better way to go?

Or am I just off-base?

Comment: You can try this way : javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
javascript_include_tag  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
javascript_include_tag "jquery-rails.js"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jRails** is a replacement for Prototype using RJS. For instance, you can use methods like `form_remote_for`, which create an AJAX form. In Rails 3.x the preferred method is to use UJS with `:remote => true` instead.

**jquery-ujs** is a replacement for Prototype using UJS. UJS is the preferred method of using jQuery in Rails 3.x.

More info: [jQuery with Rails 3](http://joshhuckabee.com/jquery-rails-3)

Comment: I already have Rails 3 installed, so it looks like I shouldn't even worry about jRails. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

jRails was a solution to use jQuery in Rails 2.x and still use the same helper methods.

Rails 3 is js-library agnostic and uses unobtrusive javascript by default. So the helper are gone, but they added an extra option `:remote => true` instead. 
By default a new Rails 3 project will use  the prototype `rails.js`. If you want to use jQuery, you need to use jquery-ujs. Installing it is very easy if you use the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) gem.

So in short:

- if you are still using Rails 2 and want to use the standard helpers like `link_to_remote, ...` use jRails. You could also write unontrusive js in Rails 2, but there is no support.
- If you are using Rails 3, you can only use `jquery-ujs` : it allows you to use `form_for`, `link_to` unobtrusively with jQuery. jRails is not intended to be used with Rails 3.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail, nathanvda

Answer (score 0):

I recommend neither.  The rails helpers to create AJAX requests end up being a support headache over time.

Checkout this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript

Comment: The railscast you point to will only work with jquery if you install jquery-ujs.